# Solve ODE $x^2 y' + xy = y ^2$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

> $x^2 y' + xy = y ^2$ and $y(1)=1$.

Solution

> let $u = \frac{y}{x}$, then $y' = u+xu'$, we have
> $$xu' = u^2 - 2u \Rightarrow \frac{du}{u^2-2u} = \frac{dx}{x}. $$
> Integraling on both sides of the equation, we have
> $$ \frac{1}{2} \ln \left| \frac{u-2}{u}\right| = \ln |x| + C_1 \Rightarrow \frac{u-2}{u} = Cx^2$$
> ...

My doubt is the last step, why the abs symbol can be removed ? i think it should be
$$
\left| \frac{u-2}{u} \right| = e^{C_1^2}x^2.
$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could also find $(xy)'=\dfrac{(xy)^2}{x^3}$, which is separable and leads to $\dfrac1{xy}=\dfrac1{2x^2}+C$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $$\frac 1 2 \ln \left\lvert \frac {u - 2} u \right\rvert = \ln \lvert x \rvert + C_1$$

which gives $$\ln \left\lvert \frac {u - 2} u \right\rvert = 2\ln \lvert x \rvert + C_2$$

which gives $$\ln \left\lvert \frac {u - 2} u \right\rvert = \ln x^2 + C_2$$

which gives $$\left\lvert \frac {u - 2} u \right\rvert = C_3x^2$$

which gives $$\frac {u - 2} u = C_4x^2,$$

where $$C_1, C_2, C_3, C_4 \in \mathbb{R}.$$

Thus, removing the absolute value signs simply results in yet another different constant term. In other words, all of these equations are equivalent up to a constant, whose value may be determined based on some set of initial conditions. In particular, you are asking about the last step, where we can see that $C_4$ is nothing but $\pm C_3$. Note that in practice, one may also tend to omit several of the intermediate steps I have shown, since they only involve trivial algebraic manipulation.

Comment: Thank you!  the step of $C_3 \to C_4$, I think whether the abs can be removed depends on the value of $u$, so we cant straightly remove it ?

Comment: @maplgebra And why would you say that? As mentioned in my answer above, no matter what the value of $u$ is, we have already accounted for all possible cases with the constant $C_4$. This is another way of saying that the equation is correct up to a constant term.

Comment: I got it! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

This is correct:
$$
\left|\frac{u-2}{u}\right|=e^{C}\, x^2
$$

Note that the exponential only means that the constant is positive. And the absolute value means that there are two kinds of solutions:
$$
\frac{u-2}{u}=e^{C}\, x^2
$$
and
$$
\frac{u-2}{u}=-e^{C}\, x^2
$$
which only differ by the sign of the constant. So we can replace the positive constant $e^C$ by an *arbitrary* one $C_1$ and collect both solutions in the single expression
$$
\frac{u-2}{u}=C_1\, x^2
$$